# Tracking greenlets created in a bottle request

Tags: python-2.7, bottle, gevent

I am using Bottle monkey patched with gevent. One of  the things I want to monitor is the # of greenlets created within a Bottle request context. I couldn't find a way to have some callback fire off when a greenlet is created. I was hoping for something that allows me to do something similar to the function:

```
@gevent.register_on_greenlet_creation
def callback(greenlet_context):
  request_route = bottle.request.route
  send_metric_for_greenlet_created(request_route)
```

However, it doesn't look like gevent has any type of hooks. Because I am monkey patching everything with gevent, it is way too much overhead to add this type of callback when a network request is executed for every single instance. Is there a better way to monitor this?

Comment: Just curious (also checking whether this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/224665)): what do you need the greenlet count for?

Comment: @ronrothmanℝℝ I want to have a way to understand what routes are populating the event pool with a lot of greenlets, and monitor that metric.

Comment: How is that different from counting the number of times each route is called? Which is to say: can't you simply increment a metric at the beginning of each route handler? I'm not sure what "populating the event pool" means.